# How to integrate sms application using sms gateway in android?

Tags: android

In my application I need to **integrate SMS application**. So for that using intent I have integrated sms application into my project. But my application has to send **bulk data** so for that I have to use sms gateway. How to use sms gateway in android?
Please help me regarding this...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SMS gateways usually use a http post or xml post protocol. So you must open an http connection and set the required parameters. Which differ per sms gateway. Unfortunately there is still not a standard for that.

Another option is using the smpp protocol, but it is more of a burden and not convenient when just trying to send a couple of messages.